# Prove that the zeros of $J_p(x)$ and $J_{p+1}(x)$ alternate.

Tags: real-analysis

> By definition the Bessel function $J_p(x)$ is the unique series solution to Bessel's equation $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-p^2)y=0$ which starts (assume $p$ is a non-negative integer, to avoid explanations), $$\frac{x^p}{2^pp!} \left( 1-\frac{x^2}{2^21!(p+1)}+\frac{x^4}{2^22!(p+1)(p+2)}-\cdots \right).$$
>   From the series, it is not difficult to see using term-by-term differentiation that $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^{-p}J_p)=-x^{-p}J_{p+1}.$$
>   Assuming the above facts, prove that the zeros of $J_p(x)$ and $J_{p+1}(x)$ alternate (like the zeros of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$).

I am studying [Sturm separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_separation_theorem) and [Sturm comparison theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem)
. From $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{-p}J_p)=-x^{-p}J_{p+1}$, I get $-pJ_p+xJ^{'}_p=-xJ_{p+1}.$ So, $J^{'}_p=-J_{p+1}$ when $J_p=0.$ $J^{'}_p$ changes sign at successive zeros $a$ and $b$ of $J_p$, so is $J_{p+1}$. By Bolzano's Theorem, $J_{p+1}$ has at least one zero on $(a,b).$ But how to show $J_{p+1}$ has exactly one zero on $(a,b)$?

Comment: What is the actual question? The question body already contains a proof of the fact that the zeroes of $J_p$ and $J_{p+1}$ are interlaced.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry for my ignorance. How the zeroes of $J_p$ and $J_{p+1}$ are interlaced?

Answer (score 1):

Due to your intro, when $J_{p+1}(\xi)=0$ we have that $\xi$ is a stationary point for $J_p$. In particular not a zero, since all the zeroes of $J_p$ are simple due to Bessel differential equation. On the other hand between two consecutive real zeroes$^{(*)}$ of $J_{p+1}$ there is a zero of $J_{p+1}'$ by Rolle's theorem, hence a zero of $J_p$. This leads to the fact that the real zeroes of $J_p$ and $J_{p+1}$ are interlaced / interleaved.

You may also prove that $^{(*)}$*all* the zeroes of $J_p$ and $J_{p+1}$ are real.

Comment: Sorry, I have not learned what you said, such as, "stationary point""simple".

Comment: @Hongyan: so you are dealing with Bessel functions without basic concepts from Calculus and Algebra? Bah. Anyway, "$\xi$ is a stationary point for $f$" means $f'(\xi)=0$ and "$\xi$ is a simple root for $f$" means that $f(\xi)=0$ but $f'(\xi)\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks! I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate $-pJ_p+xJ^{'}_p=-xJ_{p+1}$ and use $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-p^2)y=0$, I get $J_p=J^{'}_{p+1}$ when $J_{p+1}=0$. By the same reasoning, there is a zero of $J_p$ between successive zeroes of $J_{p+1}$. That completes the argument.